# Riak pid - where is it and is one created

Tags: riak

I installed the riak ubuntu package.  Is there a riak.pid?  My node is running but nothing on the machine.  I need for monit.  There is a /var/run/riak dir but no pid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: there isn't one.

That being said, a post to our mailing list may help you:

http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2011-October/006064.html

```
check process riak matching "/path/to/riak/erts-5.7.5/bin/beam"
   group riak
   start program = "/path/to/riak/bin/riak start"
   if failed host localhost port 8098
        protocol HTTP request "/" then alert
```

(Note you will need to change the erlang version to the one you are currently using)

Comment: Did not work.  service is running.  service riak ping
Attempting to restart script through sudo -u riak
pong

telnet localhost 8098
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: Yes..I did change the version